# uniqeness of integer solution of linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

can you help me how to calculate the unique integer solution of linear equations(underdetermined integer linear system) and what are the uniqueness conditions of this solution?
I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: where can i find your System?

Comment: If it's integer elements (or even rational) I'd reccon there would either be no solution or infinite number of solutions.

Comment: In integer linear systems.we have underdetermined linear system for example 6unknown variable and for equation that unknown variables just take -1,1.we have multiple solutions .I am looking for a unique solution (in matlab)without any optimization condition.for example:x1+x3+x4=y1,-x1+x2-x5=y2,-x4+x5+x6=y3,-x2-x4-x6=y4.if y={3,-1,-1,-1}we have more than one answer.how can find just the unique solution??